Did the quality of prisms affect the acceptance of Newton's light experiments?
My question starts with the following statement from a book I'm reading

"Moreover, repetition of a well-established experience could give results that made it be called into question: an important example is that of Newton's light scattering experiment, which initially failed in France, Italy and the Netherlands because of the inferior quality of the prisms used"

I found this fact quite amusing and I decided to keep searching about it. However, I didn't find a lot of information surrounding the trouble that scientists had replicating this experiment, nor the quality of the prisms. In fact, I just found one article that mentions it:

Within a week, Hooke fired off his first attack on Newton's report, and other critics—both at home and abroad—rapidly followed suit. They were dissatisfied not only with the difficulties of replicating his results, but also with his methodological arguments, and a couple of months later Newton wrote to Oldenburg admitting that he should have given fuller experimental details. The status of the experiment that he claimed to be crucial continued to be challenged. Should that one single trial override the implications of many others? When competitors announced they could split Newton's supposedly basic rays into ones of different colours, he retorted that if his rivals could not replicate his work, they were using the wrong type of prism.

In this paragraph, at least for me, it seems to picture it as more of a "quick response" of Newton to his objectors, rather than an "empirical fact", if you will.
My question is if there's any more material I could read where it definitely states that the prisms used were worse, therefore the experiments failed to reproduce Newton's results.
(The book I cited is Historia de la ciencia, by Carlos Solís and Manuel Sellés. It's in Spanish and I couldn't find it translated to English, so I had to do it myself to ask here).

You might find our sister site - History of Science and Mathematics - has more expertise in this area.

Didn't know it existed, thank you!

The article cited in the footnote, Schaffer S. 1989 Glass works: Newton's prisms and the uses of experiment. The uses of experiment: studies in the natural sciences (eds , Gooding D, Pinch T& Schaffer S), pp. 67–104. Cambridge, UK: Cambridge University Press. seems to contain what you are looking for, even if it argues the failure to reproduce the experiment was not based in prism quality, but in missing clarity of the experiment's descpription and in epistemological differences in what the experiment is actually supposed to prove.
